# How to make an element padding maximuim cover its <div> horizontally

Tags: html, css

I am trying to design a dropdown menu where the child item of the menu changes color(green) but the item doesn't extend to cover all the box size horizontally leaving the remaining part in its original color.

Thank you!

HTML Doc

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container">
        <header>
        <img src="jarir.svg">
        <div id="search"><input></div>
    </header>
    <nav>
    <div class="dropdown">
    <a>All Catgories</a>
    <div class="dropdown_content">
            <a>Link1</a>
            <a>Link2</a>
            <a>Link3</a> 
    </div>

    </div> <!-- dropdown-->
     <a>Shop by Brand</a> <a>Online Exclusive</a>
    </nav>
    </div> <!-- container-->
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
#container{}
img{
    width: 130px;
    height: 45px;
}
#search, #search input{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    margin: 5px 10px;
    width:500px;
    max-width: 500px;
    min-width: 200px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
nav a{
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    float:left;
    border-bottom: 0.7mm solid red;
}
nav a:hover{
    border-bottom: 1.2mm solid #3A44F8;
}
.dropdown{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}<!-- -->
.dropdown:hover .dropdown_content {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 0px;

}
.dropdown_content a{border-bottom: 0px;}
.dropdown:hover{
    background-color:Blue;
    color: red;
}
.dropdown_content a:hover{ 
    background-color:green;
    color: yellow;
    border: 0px;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown_content {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    top: 35px;
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
    z-index: 1;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this code. There is some css changes.**
Like `.dropdown_content a{border-bottom: 0px;display: block;width: 100%;box-sizing: border-box;}`

```css
#container{}
img{
    width: 130px;
    height: 45px;
}
#search, #search input{
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    margin: 5px 10px;
    width:500px;
    max-width: 500px;
    min-width: 200px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
nav a{
    margin-right: 30px;
    padding: 10px;
    float:left;
    border-bottom: 0.7mm solid red;
}
nav a:hover{
    border-bottom: 1.2mm solid #3A44F8;
}
.dropdown{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}<!-- -->
.dropdown:hover .dropdown_content {
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 0px;

}
.dropdown_content a{border-bottom: 0px;display: block;width: 100%;box-sizing: border-box;}
.dropdown:hover{
    background-color:Blue;
    color: red;
}
.dropdown_content a:hover{ 
    background-color:green;
    color: yellow;
    border: 0px;
}
.dropdown_content {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    top: 35px;
    background-color:#f7f7f7;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2); 
    z-index: 1;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <title>Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <header>
        <img src="jarir.svg" />
        <div id="search"><input /></div>
      </header>
      <nav>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a>All Catgories</a>
          <div class="dropdown_content">
            <a>Link1</a> <a>Link2</a> <a>Link3</a>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- dropdown -->
        <a>Shop by Brand</a> <a>Online Exclusive</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
    <!-- container -->
  </body>
</html>
```